# Do I need to use os.Exit(0) when succefully terminanting an application in Go?

Tags: go, program-entry-point, exit, exit-code

I`ve recently discovered the [os.Exit](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Exit) function on Go standard library, and I`ve seen it in some tutorials as well.

Since the Go`s `func main()` does not return any value, does it matter if I simply use `return` in the `main()` function isteand of `os.Exit(0)`?

I know `os.Exit` also ignores `defers` in Go code, but in this case I just want to know if there`s no difference for the OS between `return` and `os.Exit(0)`.

Comment: "does it matter if I simply use return in the main() function isteand of os.Exit(0)" No. dead simple.

Comment: If your application requires orderly/graceful shutdown then `os.Exit()` is a bad idea. As soon as your application use buffered io, for example, you may run into troubles as buffers will most likely not be flushed on exit. Another example, is a server implementation where the server should orderly shutdown client connections before going down.

Comment: @Marcus, you can't rely on defer to do this anyway, since any signal would also cause `main` to skip defers. If you're handling all possible signals to prevent this, you should also be explicitly doing whatever cleanup you need anyway. There's still rarely a reason to use `os.Exit(0)` when you can just let `main` return, but `defer` doesn't provide the safety net n `main` some people think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the difference you described is correct, `os.Exit(0)` finishes  the program immediately, ignoring any defers. With `return` your program will finish with default code 0.

```
test-exit$ cat main.go
> package main
> 
> func main() {
>   return
> }
test-exit$ go run main.go
test-exit$ echo $? // shows status code of last executed command
> 0
```

So outside the defer case there is basically no difference.